# how to get my non-expiring token in facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i want to get non-expiring token ([facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/system-users/install-apps-and-generate-tokens#generate-token))

1. get my id by request url: [https://graph.facebook.com/{api-version}/me?access_token={access_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Bapi-version%7D/me?access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D)
2. request url by POST method: [https://graph.facebook.com/{api-version}/SYSTEM-USER-ID/access_tokens](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Bapi-version%7D/SYSTEM-USER-ID/access_tokens)

when i post reuest, aways got error like this

```json
{"error":{"message":"The system user provided is not valid.","type":"OAuthException","code":3955,"error_subcode":1690070,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Not a valid system user","error_user_msg":"The system user provided is not valid.","fbtrace_id":"AfCMBKj-goOtn_byvWFfnCA"}}
```

Is that mean i have not permission? But i am admin...

Where can i get real SYSTEM-USER-ID?

And i alas try this [query accouts](https://gist.github.com/msramalho/4fc4bbc2f7ca58e0f6dc4d6de6215dc0), but got

```json
{"data": []}
```